# How to Set the Focus on Selected Grid in GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I am implementing the Grid View in  my android application.

I want the set the focus on my selected grid. How can i get the solution for this problem ?

Comment: http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/09/android-creating-a-custom-adapter-for-gridview-buttonadapter/

Comment: not getting the grid selected, implement the same code which shown on that blog but not get the proper result

Comment: Try setFocusable(true). Normally your grid would have the focus, so what element is taking focus?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to set a flag to each grid items which indicates selected or not.
and, when selecting grid item set the flags properly and call notifyDatasetChanged() on your adapter.
this will work. I did same.

Comment: You will need to draw grid items selected condition in getView()

Comment: Solved my problem. notifyDataSetChanged + onResume

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set focus to `GridView` indeed, than call `GridView`'s `requestFocus()` method. If you need to set focus at specified item in `GridView`, than find it by `getChildAt()` and also call `requestFocus()`. You also should be sure that your device isn't in [Touch mode](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/12/touch-mode.html)